# How can I take an int from script1 and use it in script2 on c# unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm kind of new to c# and unity so you may find me stupid.

I tried using all the ways mentioned in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeOzp6KJ1j8&t=148s&ab_channel=PrefixWiz) and I got error after error. Here is [Script2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRXfn.png) and [Script1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzcSf.png)

For errors I got this:

> `Assets\ItemCollector2.cs(6,14): error CS0101: The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'ItemCollector'`

And this:

> `Assets\ItemCollector2.cs(19,17): error CS0111: Type 'ItemCollector' already defines a member called 'OnCollisionEnter2D' with the same parameter types`

What I am trying to do here is to make a game where you get points for sorting garbage into specific trash cans (for school project). I got it working with only one trashcan where if you put trash with a tag(biolagunev) in it you get a point for it but if I make another trashcan which takes trash with different tag, it overwrites the points you got from the first trashcan which is why I want to get the number of points from trashcan1 so that I can add any amount of points to it from trashcan2.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have 2 classes with the same name and the compiler doesn't know which to refer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).